# Report generation in rails 3 from query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, report

I want to **generate reports** in ruby on rails **from any database table or result of join of two tables**.

- reports should be in different **formats** such as **: pdf ,excel ,csv ,html etc..**
- Is this possible in rails 3.2.6.???

I know the **ruport** gem but don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem like `Prawn`. There's also a Railscast on how to get started, it's quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are various gems are available for different kind of reports like below:

```
pdf - pdfkit gem, wkhtmltopdf gem, pdftk plugin
```

https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf

http://rubygems.org/gems/pdfkit

```
excel - spreadsheet gem
```

https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

```
csv - csv gem
```

http://rubygems.org/gems/fastercsv

```
etc..
```

You can use or utilize as per your requirements.